# Why a hex file is used in burning program in micro controller?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, pic, atmel

When ever we program a micro controller we convert the C file into a hex file and then we burn that into controller.

My question is that why a hex file only, is that hex file a hexadecimal version of binary executable?
If yes then why do not we use a binary file instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about an "intel hex" file the reason being is that it is ascii which makes it easy to examine and parse.  true, it is innefficient in one way but compared to a raw binary it might be smaller.  With a raw binary you only have one if any address associated, the starting address (not embedded in the file) in a hex file or motorola srecord which is a similar and often used format as well.  both the ihex and srec formats are basically lines of ascii/hex numbers that represent a type a starting address, length data, and a checksum.  there are non data lines in there but much of it will be data.  so if your program has a few bytes at address 0x1000 and a few bytes at 0x80000000 then a .bin file would be at its smallest 0x8000000-0x1000 plus a few bytes but would typically be 0x80000000+ a few bytes (right, 2 gigabytes).  Where an ihex or srec would be in the dozens of bytes total.   the ihex and srec have built in checksums to help protect against corrupt files, not perfect of course but better than nothing at all...

Since then elf and coff and other formats have become popular.  these are also based on blocks of data and not a complete memory image.  these are binary, not ascii formats, but they are not just a memory image.  chunks of data with address, type, etc are provided.

Because the ihex and srec are so simple to create and parse they will continue to be used for a long time, it does not take a lot of resources in a bootloader for example to handle receiving an ihex or srec file. (same with a binary of course, but the binary has a lot of fill data in it costing a lot of unnecessary transmission time).